# Adding icons to a title attribute of Ant Designs Blazor (DescriptionsItem)

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-5.0, ant-design-blazor

Ant Design Blazor has a [descriptions component](https://antblazor.com/en-US/components/descriptions) for generating key/value pair elements. I'd like to add an [icon](https://antblazor.com/en-US/components/icon) and [tooltip](https://antblazor.com/en-US/components/tooltip) as the key/title. The problem is, that the title is set as an attribute like this:

```
<DescriptionsItem Title="Billing Mode">Prepaid</DescriptionsItem>
```

I have tried to set `Title` as child element, cause this would allow me to add any other components inside it:

```
<DescriptionsItem>
    <Title>My title</Title>
    My Text
</DescriptionsItem>
```

But this doesn't work, `<Title>` is a standalone component for html titles like `h1, h2, ...` which means both got rendered in the value section without any title:

[image]

I couldn't find a way to render other components in the title attribute, it just works in the body/value like this:

```
<DescriptionsItem Title="Created">
    <Tooltip Placement="@PlacementType.Bottom" Title="creationIconTitle">
        <Icon Type="plus-circle" Theme="outline" />
    </Tooltip>
    @Community.Created.ToLocalTime().ToString("G")
</DescriptionsItem>
```

But I'd like to have the icon in the title. Is there a way to realize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in luck! [The source](https://github.com/ant-design-blazor/ant-design-blazor/blob/master/components/descriptions/IDescriptionsItem.cs) says the developers thought of this and added a `TitleTemplate` [`RenderFragment`](https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/). Thus you can do something like:

```
<Descriptions Title="Descriptions">
    <DescriptionsItem>
        <TitleTemplate>
            <AntDesign.Tooltip Placement="@PlacementType.Bottom">
                <AntDesign.Icon Type="plus-circle" Theme="outline" />
            </AntDesign.Tooltip>
            31.10.2008 17:04:32
        </TitleTemplate>
    </DescriptionsItem>
</Descriptions>
```

This TitleTemplate is used over the Title, if defined [source](https://github.com/ant-design-blazor/ant-design-blazor/blob/07c0ef80447ec407c390c491d5e4344d10c74c9a/components/descriptions/Descriptions.razor#L32)